# How to join the below two collection for customer & Customer Address I want to use on grid

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, join-table

How to join the below two collection for customer & Customer Address I want to use on grid

```
$entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode('customer_address');
$customerAddressCollection = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection()->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType);
```

and

```
$entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode('customer');
$customerCollection = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection()->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the code below.

It allow you to change the entities you want to merge and give you a `$customCollection` to set to your grid.

```
    // init
    $entitiesToMerge = array('customer_address', 'customer');
    $entitiesData = array();

    // get the entities objects and data
    if (!empty($entitiesToMerge)) {
        foreach($entitiesToMerge as $entityCode) {
            $entity = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode($entityCode);
            $entitiesData['id'][]         = $entity->getId();
            $entitiesData['additional'][] = $entity->getAdditionalAttributeTable();
        }
    }
    // sanitize
    $entitiesData['id']          = array_unique($entitiesData['id']);
    $entitiesData['additional']  = array_unique($entitiesData['additional']);

    // create custom collection
    $customCollection = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection();

    //filter the collection with the entity_types
    $customCollection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.entity_type_id', array('in' => $entitiesData['id']));
    // join additionnal attributes data table
    if (!empty($entitiesData['additional'])) {
        foreach($entitiesData['additional'] as $idx => $additionalTable) {
            $customCollection->join(
                array('additional_table_' . $idx => $additionalTable),
                'additional_table_' . $idx . '.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id'
        );
        }
    }
    // check the request
    mage::log($customCollection->getSelect()->assemble());
```